# How do I fix the error of needing the "new" keyword when compiling my Typescript code using `ts-node`

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, ts-node

I am trying to run a Typescript program that seems to always break when it reaches a line of code where a class calls its parent using `super`.

```
class A extends B {
   constructor(endpoint: string) {
        super(endpoint) // error here
   }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
TypeError: Class constructor Connection cannot be invoked without 'new'
(associated_js_file.js)
 var _this = _super.call(this, endpoint) || this
```

I have seen previous questions that are similar but I have tried their solutions to no avail.

What I have done:

1. Changed my Node version from `v18.6.0` to `v16.16.0` (someone told me that the program was working for them and this was the only difference in our Node or ts-node versions).
2. I read in other questions that `ts-node` has a default target of es5, which causes an error when it is compiled to Javascript. I have checked the `target` using `ts-node --showConfig`, where it shows the target is es6.

For added measure, I added a tsconfig.json file that looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6"
  }
}
```

and ran `ts-node --project tsconfig.json main.ts`.

Why is my program still having the same error?

Comment: Shouldn't be related to the node version. The problem is indeed that the executed code was transpiled to ES5.

Comment: Not able to [reproduce here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-wsusty). You can run `npm start` to see the output.

Comment: @Bergi everything points to it being transpiled to ES6; is there anything else I should change?

Comment: Is the problematic class in *main.ts* itself, or is it imported somehow?

Comment: It is imported from another file

Comment: Are you certain that it's `ts-node` that is transpiling that file? Maybe you also have some other build system in place, and `ts-node` imports the output of that?